# connecting firebase storage with angular 7

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular6-json-schema-form

i want to retrieve a photo from firebase storage to angular 7 and when i run the app some error is showed and i can't solved it .

my code is showen below :

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from 'angularfire2/storage';

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    AngularFireStorageModule
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import firebase from 'firebase/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  firestore = firebase.storage();
  storageRef = firebase.storage.ref();

  title = 'aaa';
  constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) { }
  display() {
    this.storageRef = firebase.storage.ref('rasool/download2.jpg');
    this.storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    console.log(url);
});
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="display()"></button>
```

**the error is showed in cli :**

> WARNING in ./src/app/app.component.ts 8:25-33 "export 'default'
>   (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/firestore'
>
> WARNING in ./src/app/app.component.ts 9:26-34 "export 'default'
>   (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/firestore'
>
> WARNING in ./src/app/app.component.ts 13:26-34 "export 'default'
>   (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/firestore' i
>   ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.

**how can i solve this error please help me**

**I have another question , Is below section of code is right ???**

```
this.storageRef = firebase.storage.ref('rasool/download2.jpg');
this.storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
console.log(url);
```

Comment: Try changing the import to `import { firebase } from '@firebase/app'` and
`import '@firebase/firestorage'`

Comment: The "errors" that you have posted are _warnings_, which should be ignored. Please post the _actual_ error.

Answer (score 0):

For TypeScript:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

In AppComponent:

```
storage = firebase.storage();        // Cloud Storage
firestore = firebase.firestore();    // Cloud Firestore
```

Or you can use `AngularFireStorage` directly to get the storage reference:

```
export class AppComponent {

  storageRef: AngularFireStorageReference;

  constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) { }

  display() {
    this.storageRef = afStorage.ref('rasool/download2.jpg');
    this.storageRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => console.log(url));
  }
}
```

Comment: This will probably work, but will also import everything from firebase, which he won't need.

Comment: Yes, which is why I mentioned to use `AngularFireStorage` instead.

Comment: True, my bad. Somehow didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

To connect Firebase Storage with Angular we need to first import the following modules in the app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
```

add imports for AngularFireModule and initialize it and also 
add an import for AngularFireStorageModule

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase,'firebase'),
AngularFireStorageModule,
```

The AngularFireStorage can be then utilized in a function by first importing

```
import { AngularFireStorage } from "@angular/fire/storage";
import { FirebaseStorage } from "@angular/fire";
```

then injecting it with the constructor, by creating a **cloudStorage** variable and assigning it to the FirebaseStorage type.

```
cloudStorage:FirebaseStorage;
constructor(private store:AngularFireStorage) { 
    this.cloudStorage= store.storage.app.storage();
  }
```

The *cloudStorage* variable can then used to retreive reference with which we can perform the cloud functions.

> Working on Angular 8.2.2